# Permissions for /system/etc

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-4, clockworkmod-recovery, permissions, system

I was trying to enable writing titanium backups to the SDCard by editing the file:

`/system/etc/permissions/platform.xml`

However I was not paying attention and now everytime I boot up I get spammed with error messages "Unfortunatley, the process com.google.process.gapps has stopped". All apps also produce a force close saying about the same thing. Continuously. I can recieve calls and open up a couple of apps but only by the small window between closing error messages. Here are the steps I took when editing the platform.xml

First I edited the file as suggested:

Original:

Add the media_rw group:

Then I copied the file back to the SDCard. After that I overwrote it in /system/etc/permissions. Not realizing the permissions were incorrect. I restarted the device and started getting errors. I assumed it was the file permissions so I started up ADB and entered the following lines:

```
mount | grep system
mount -o rw,remount /dev/block/platform/msm_sdcc.1/by-name/system /system
chmod 326 /system/etc

chmod 644 /system/etc/permissions/platform.xml
chmod 644 /system/etc 

mount -o ro,remount /dev/block/platform/msm_sdcc.1/by-name/system /system
```

That changed the file permissions so I rebooted by my device and got stuck in a boot loop.

So I rebooted into Clockworkmod recovery and tried to restore a working backup of my stock ROM. Got past the boot loop but still spammed by errors, so I tried to restore just the /system partition from the recovery using Clockwork's advanced tab. Seems like the errors are even worse. I wanted to know if by my description someone could give me a push in the right direction. Does anyone know what permissions the /system/etc folder is supposed to have? I suspect the reason this is happening is because I changed the /system/etc permissions instead of just changing /system/etc/permissions. Please offer any knowledge you have. I've pretty much exhausted the first few pages of Google and I don't want to give up and factory reset just yet.

**UPDATE:** 
I gave in and factory reset. However I still think the permissions remain incorrect. I get no errors or problems after factory reset and clearing of dalvik and cache. But if I try to restore my nandroid taken before the problems occured I get the same spamming of errors. A ls -l of those directories would give me some hope.

Comment: Have you tried to reflash the GApps package?

Comment: I haven't flashed anything new in fear that it was a simple fix. Its not just gapps. Its also everything else Rhapsody, Titanium Backup, All other apps on my phone that present the force closed. That's why I think its a permission issue.

Comment: I'll add this anyway - did you clear cache and dalvik-cache in recovery?

Comment: @HasH_BrowN Yes tried that, I believe if someone could check their /system and /system/etc directories andalso the /system/etc/permissions and /system/etc/permissions/platform.xml directories and files and show me the permissions that are set on those directories I could fix it. Would you mind providing this info?

Comment: The file is too large for comments and it doesnt qualify as an answer so i cant post it.

Comment: Extract your ROM on the PC and pull the platform.xml out, compare it that way. Did you include `-system` in your nandroid?

Comment: I use clockwork so I don't know if it included the /system. I just click backup. I'm using the stock ROM. Your suggesting I go download the stock ROM and I can see file permissions on my PC? Would you be open to emailing me that other stuff because it's too big? I think the part I messed up was chmod 644 /system/etc I think that folder is supposed to be 755.

Comment: @Cameron the *folder `/system/etc`* has `644`? That's definitely wrong, missing the "execute" bit nothing can change into it. Your assumption of `755` is making sense here, as it is `644` + `111`, i.e. adding the "execute bit".